# Firebase Database Reference Error: No such instance field: 'mDatabaseReference'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database to store data for a project. I'm using Android Studio and Java to create a mobile app. In this particular activity, a new user is filling out a form to sign up for the service. Once they input their info and hit the submit button, the on click handles that info and inserts it into the Database.

Here is the relevant code for that class:

```
public class CreateUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

private List<String> mInterestList;

private EditText mUsername;
private EditText mPassword;
private EditText mEmail;
private EditText mLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user);

    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mInterestList = new ArrayList<>();

    mUsername = findViewById(R.id.text_username);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.text_password);
    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.text_email);
    mLocation = findViewById(R.id.text_location);
}

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view;
    boolean isChecked = checkbox.isChecked();
    String interest = checkbox.getText().toString();

    if(isChecked) {
        mInterestList.add(interest);
    }else {
        mInterestList.remove(interest);
    }
}

public void onSaveUser(View view) {
    String username = mUsername.getText().toString();
    String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
    String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
    String location = mLocation.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username) ||
        TextUtils.isEmpty(password) ||
        TextUtils.isEmpty(email) ||
        TextUtils.isEmpty(location) ||
        mInterestList.size() == 0) {
        displayToast("Please enter values for all fields");
    }else {
        List<String> interests = mInterestList;
        User user = new User(username, password, email, location, interests, null);

        mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(username).setValue(user, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if(databaseError != null) {
                    Log.e(GetTogetherApp.LOG_TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
                }else{
                    displayToast("User created!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As I've run through breakpoints the error seems to fire on this line:

```
mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(username).setValue()
```

Specifically once I try and enter into the setValue() method. The other two child() calls work to find the path as intended. I have the database reference set as a member variable, so I'm not sure why it seems to lose it at that point.

Here's a look at my database structure

[Firebase Database Structure Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sQ04.png)

Error in Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: Given the code you shared, that error message seems unlikely at first glance. Can you show a screenshot of the error you get?

Comment: Absolutely, let me upload some to imgur

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/BamQmx0)

Comment: That's an error message in the variable inspector in the Android Studio debugger. It means that where the error occurs, there is no variable `mDatabaseReference` so the debugger can't show its value. You can find the actual cause of the problem by inspecting the `InvocationTargetException e`.

Comment: So a try/catch would filter that exception and allow me to see it, I'm gussing.

Comment: That's one option, and then `Log.e()` it. But if you already have it in the debugger in your screenshot, you can also hover over `e` and see what the debugger shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in your screenshot is in the variable inspector in the Android Studio debugger. It means that where the error occurs, there is no variable `mDatabaseReference` so the debugger can't show its value. This is not the actual cause of the crash, merely the debugger telling you that it can't show you something you asked for.

You can find the actual cause of the problem by inspecting the `InvocationTargetException e`.

Comment: I've wrapped it in a try/catch once before and Log.e the message. It comes out with a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

From what I've read that's a runtime error, that is essentially an exception wrapped in another exception. It was unclear to me how I would unwrap that outer exception to show the contents of what is really wrong.

Comment: ok. so it seems there's a null pointer exception. I have no idea where that could be happening... since the error gets thrown from INSIDE Firebase's code.. But at least I've tracked it down to that

[The Underlying Exception] (https://imgur.com/a/kc9OQAL)